# How to keep track of changes in Array in Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am using the Kendo Treeview Control and need to be able to handle updates to my Back end when user check or unchecked an item. It emits an checkedChange which gives me an object that has a the checked item and all children, but it does not tell me if the item is checked. There is a selectedKeys collection which stores all the selected keys but that seems to be updated after the checkChange Event is fired which means i will not get the correct answer as the newly checked item is not in collection. Is there a wy to have the lookup wait till the collection is updated ?
Also is there a way to get the changes of the collection after the update maybe i can use taht to determine what keys have been added and deleted ?

Here is the StackBlitz sample which uses the component [StackBlitz Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-tree-remote-data?file=app%2Fkendo-tree%2Fkendo-tree.component.ts)

Comment: Please add a minimal example in code here so we can see what you're doing.

Comment: It’s in the stack blitz which shows exactly what is happening, there is no way to provide a meaningful short snipped

Comment: Quote: "...it does not tell me if the item is checked...". Yes it does. In your own example this line `console.log(this.checkedKeys.indexOf($event.item.dataItem.guid));` prints -1 in the console if the item's new state is checked and the previous index if it is unchecked and to be removed from the list.

Comment: There is the problem, because the on click fires before the checkedKeys is updated the result is reversed. When it is checked it says index of -1 which means it’s not in the array then when you uncheck it shows the index since it is currently in the array before it is removed.

Comment: And what else could you ask for? You know which keys were checked or unchecked and send only those keys to your back-end for update. On the other hand, why would you care about onClick firing before checkedChange? You don't use onClick in your example, nor do you need it.

Comment: Because the checkedKeys array can be updated from outside so using this logic might not work if there was another update and actually pushed the key into array which means it will have index of > -1 . Just because it works in small scope it’s not a solid approach. That’s why I am locking for a way to update the checkedKeys prior to running the indexOf

Answer (score -1):

Use the `checkedKeysChange` -event for which you have already a handler:

`(checkedKeysChange)="selectUpdate($event)"`

There you have access to the updated array of selected keys.

Check this Stackblitz based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/kendo-tree-remote-data-vmrria

Comment: More about it in https://www.telerik.com/forums/treeview-checkedchange-event

Comment: I don’t want all keys I want to know only the checkbox which was clicked and if it is checked or unchecked. What you tell me is what I already have

Comment: Did you check the Stackblitz example I made? It shows all the **checked** keys. Combined with what I said in my other comment - "Quote: "...it does not tell me if the item is checked...". Yes it does. In your own example this line console.log(this.checkedKeys.indexOf($event.item.dataItem.guid)); prints -1 in the console if the item's new state is checked and the previous index if it is unchecked and to be removed from the list. –". There you have all you are asking for!!

Comment: My question from the get go was how can I make sure that the keys updated before I check if an item is in the array. I is not a good practice for some code to assume a -1 index if it’s in array and then in another call a > -1. We are going in circles about something I knew before I posted a question how to fix the problem.

Comment: Please, read your question once more. You said that, "There is a selectedKeys collection which stores all the selected keys but that seems to be updated after the checkChange Event is fired which means i will not get the correct answer as the newly checked item is not in collection.". You are correct, selectedKeys is updated after the `checkedChange` is fired. But there is the other event `checkedKeysChange`. When it fires the `selectedKeys` has already been updated.